# jQuery ajax - change jQuery target value with form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple jQuery form using the jQuery form plugin from malsup (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and ajax that I'm using for testing (below).

On my page, I have multiple forms.

On submitting a form, I need the results to be posted to a specific div (I'm using the "Target" method).

I've been trying to figure out how I can change the "Target" for the results based on what form was submitted.  I would assume (with my VERY limited jQuery knowledge) that if I added a hidden field to each form, I could do an if statement (I found something similar searching stack overflow but couldn't get it to work for my situation) to tell jQuery which target to use but am not sure how to go about doing this (None of my attempts have worked!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        target: '#info1', 
        success: function() { 
            $('#info1').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="htmlForm" action="inc/test_ajax5.lasso" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="info1" />
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" /> <br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="" /> <br />
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Echo as HTML" /> 
</form>
<hr />
<div id="info1"></div>
<hr />
<div id="info2"></div>
```

Comment: does each form has seperate ajaxform submit or all the form submit is handled by a single function. Here I can see only a single form.

Answer (score 2):

You can try handling everything on the success callback instead of using target.

HTML:

```
<form id="htmlForm" action="inc/test_ajax5.lasso" method="post">
<input id="target" type="hidden" name="formName" value="info1" />
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="" /> <br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="" /> <br />
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Echo as HTML" /> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { 
            var targetid = $form.find("#target").val(); //hidden field value

            $('#' + targetid).html(responseText).fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: That makes sense - I hadn't set up anything for the success callback yet.  Does this mean that the target callback cannot be changed in a similar way?

Comment: Also, I've run into something else along the same lines.  Is is possible to change the "#htmlForm in the same fashion?  It seems that for each form, this needs to be different.  When I go to "form2" using #htmlForm as the form ID, the form gets sent as a content-type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "XMLHttpRequest".  IT seems to be ignoring the jquery all together!  It doesn't matter if I chose the second form first, it ignores any form requests except the first one on the page.  If I add another jQuery "block" and change #htmlForm to #htmlForm2 they both work.

Comment: Try using a class for all the forms $(".htmlForm").

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hidden field you can assign **class** to each form with name of div where you want put its response;  like below:

```
 <form id="htmlForm" action="inc/test_ajax5.lasso"  class="info1" method="post">

 <form id="htmlForm2" action="inc/test_ajax5.lasso"  class="info2" method="post">
```

and you can use that in  you code as below:

```
$('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
    target: '#' + $('#htmlForm').attr('class'), 
    success: function() { 
        $('#' + $('#htmlForm').attr('class')).fadeIn('slow'); 
    } 
});
```