# Servlet loads a new page

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I have the following problem:

I have two servlets, one returns a navigation. There are categories and subcategories that the servlet gets through the DAO. I use the following script to get the servlets result on the right position:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
                $('#navigation').load('Navigation');
                $('#content').load('Content');
            });
```

Below my navigation div, I have a content div. As you can see, i am loading the content-servlet. In my navigation; i have the following elements:

```
<li><a><form action='Content' method='get'><button type='submit'>"
                                + k2.getKName() + "</button><input type='hidden' name='category' value='"+ k2.getKategorieNr() + "'/></form></a></li>
```

Now when I click on a subcategory, the button will call the content servlet. The problem is, that it loads a new page without the navigation. So I can only see the code that the servlet returns in a new page.

How can I get the result of the content servlet inside my previous page as it already works for my navigation servlet?

Answer (score 1):

When you load your page initially, `$("#navigation").load("Navigation")` makes an AJAX request to your `Navigation` servlet and pastes the HTML response from the servlet back into an element like `<div id="navigation">`.

When you click your button in the form, you are making a top-level full page request to the same servlet, and the response content will replace the whole browser window, not paste it into the page like you are getting with jQuery `load`.

The easiest way to address this may be with the jQuery ajaxForm plugin:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

where you would do something in your ready callback like

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
            $('#navigation').load('Navigation');
            $('#content').load('Content');
            $('#formId').ajaxForm({target: '#content'});
        });
```

Of course you need to add an ID to your form element so you can easily find it with jQuery.

See 
[jQuery ajax - change jQuery target value with form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971952/jquery-ajax-change-jquery-target-value-with-form-submit)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This seems legit. I will try it out later. One question: Can you recommend me another way how to solve the intercommunication problem with my servlets without using jQuery at all?

Comment: Now my servlets aren't loading :(

Comment: you were already using jQuery.  And if you're doing AJAX, of any kind, you want to use jQuery.  (Or something else built on top of jQuery.)